# Cannot duplicate Donut

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, edit-mode, duplicate

I am doing this Blender Guru Tutorial "How To make a Donut". At about [Blender Beginner Tutorial Part 3: Modifiers 03:20 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wKnPclzYY8&t=200s) Blender Guru is making a duplicate of a selection (separate the donut).

I am trying to do the same but somehow I cannot make the duplicate.
Here is my blend file:
https://mega.nz/file/DzZEkR7A#B9xjV-H83w_UndL4AFaC6bWvsFH0sna4yAt30Kt93aY

---

The part I need help with is that when I duplicate and try to separate, the donut splits in half, not like in Blender guru's video

Comment: Please provide more details. Also, please don't expect people to just download you file and help you out. Details about what you did, what exactly you are not able to do, and what you want to do should be provided in the question itself. Please use the edit button under the question to povide more details.

Comment: I made donut same like video and when I duplicate and try to separate, the donut splits in half, not like in Blender guru's video

Answer (score 2):

You've duplicated several times the top of your original mesh, so now you have overlapping vertices. Also, you have separated the original top of the original mesh; now as you see the original torus is cut off.

To fix that, in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* in order to keep only one mesh. Back to *Object* mode, duplicate the top, keep one top selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select the bottom object, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join into one object. Switch to *Edit* mode, move the top part towards the bottom part with some <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> until it matches the bottom part. Then select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* to merge the top and bottom vertices.

Now you have a top that you'll use as icing, and you've rebuilt the bottom part.

Comment: Ah, this one's definitely better than mine. Mine worked, but honestly, a bit compliccated for a beginner. Why couldn't I think of this? Thanks, learnt a little bit.

Comment: Yours is OK but I thought he first needed to fix his current file ;)

Answer (score 1):

I went through your file. You have duplicated the top part of the cube wayyy too many times, but since it in the edit mode you might have not understood it. So probably don't do anything with that right now.

Now I don't know that video, but to only seperate the upper part, you first need to duplicate it using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then right after that, without doing anything else, click <kbd>P</kbd> and choose **Selection**. This will seperate the duplicated mesh.

Just in case you plan to not make the entire original mesh once again, this is what to do.

So first thing first you are going to have to clean up this duplicated mess. Click on one the vertices. Now click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This will select all linked vertices and now click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection. Finally click X and select vertices from the options.

Now go to object mode and position it back to where it roughly was. Try to be precise as this will help. Now joint the two meshes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Now go to edit mode click <kbd>M</kbd> and select merge by distance.

Now to seperate, select the upper part, click <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate and then right after that, without doing anything else, click <kbd>P</kbd> and choose Selection. This will seperate the duplicated mesh.

I would suggest you to do the entire thing once again from scratch, as since you are a beginner you might mess up with the joining if the merge by distance doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate the Donut object:

1. Select the Donut
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
3. Move the mouse

Watched the video; he did the duplication of only one half of the donut.

If you want to do the same:

1. Select the Donut
2. Press Tab to get into Edit Mode
3. Press 1 at the Numpad to adjust the View
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle X-Ray
5. Box select half of the donut
6. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate
7. Move the mouse to replace, or Right Click to preserve location of the duplicate

Comment: First of all, it's Shift+D not Ctrl + D.  Also it seems that the person is not having trouble with just duplication but also seperation.

Comment: The question is about duplication.
And I immediately fixed myself, I just used to another layout.

Comment: I was typing the comment when you had not corrected it. Secondly, see the part in the brackets " (separate the donut)" The question is vague, and doesn't exactly specify something completely. Which is why I asked the person to edit and provide more details

Comment: I went through his file. The upper part of the donut was duplicated in the edit mode atleast about 10 times. Which is why I know that the question is not just about the duplication, but also about seperation.

Comment: then can you tell me what the problem is? i do all the steps the same way, but again the donut is split in two, as if the copying process was not done